# Java: How do I make my program print without two extra dots?

Tags: java

This program needs to print `a.b.c.` but it prints `a.b.c...`
How do I eliminate the last dot in output.
The program has to work with user ending loop with  "."

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class dots1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input;
        String output = "";
        System.out.println("Hello! I print out an acronym. ");
        do {
            System.out.println("Please Enter a Character");
            input = s.nextLine();
            output = output+input+".";
        } while (!input.equals("."));
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Because your exit condition is "." and you add it to output and add another dot. Try following:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = "";
    String output = "";
    System.out.println("Hello! I print out an acronym. ");
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Please Enter a Character");
        input = s.nextLine();
        if(input.equals("."))
            break;
        output = output + input + ".";
    } ;
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help been stuck in this for a while!

Comment: @EemilLaine please accept the answer if it resolved your query

Answer (score 0):

I use a little trick using a simple check to see if its not the first read.

```
    boolean isFirst=true;
    do{
        System.out.println("Please Enter a Character");
        input = s.nextLine();
        if(!isFirst) output="."+output;
        isFirst=false;
        output = output+input;
    }while(!input.equals("."));
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the do... while, you should use the the while function.

while (!input.equals(".") {

}

Comment: and instead removing last dot, you will get another one

Comment: Using while loop  doesn't solve the whole problem but using loop with Substring function helps him to resolve the problem example shown below

Answer (score 0):

You have to use substring function in java and remove the last character of the String.

**your loop end while you enter a dot in input**.

Example given below.

Try this

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    public class dots1 {
       Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input;
        String output = "";
        System.out.println("Hello! I print out an acronym. ");
        do{
            System.out.println("Please Enter a Character");
            input = s.nextLine();

            output = output+input+".";

        }while(!input.contains("."));

        System.out.println(output.substring(0, output.length() - 2));
        }
    }
```

**Output of Single Input** 
[image]

**output of Multiple Inputs**

[image]

Comment: What if my string is just one character long?

Comment: It also work with 1 character long String. you can check your own.After Running above program in Netbeans i posted the answer .

Comment: I tried this: `System.out.println("a".substring(0, "a".length() - 2));` and as it should, it throws `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.